# How to add hyperlink in the min.js function

Tags: javascript

```
function(){i.image&&(s.cover.classList.add(o+"-cover"),s.cover.style.width=i.imageWidth+"px",

 s.cover.style.backgroundImage="url("+i.image+")",
 s.cover.style.height=i.imageWidth+"px",

 i.rtl?s.toastBody.style.marginRight=i.imageWidth+10+"px":s.toastBody.style.marginLeft=i.imageWidth+10+"px",s.toast.appendChild(s.cover))}(),
```

the outcome for javascript above is as below:

```
<div class="iziToast-cover" style="width: 70px; background-image:url”../img/123.jpg”);"></div>
```

i would like to add a onclick function on it to become:

```
<div class="iziToast-cover" **onclick="location.href='newurl.html';"** style="width: 70px; background-image: url”../img/123.jpg”);"></div>
```

I have try s.cover.onclick.location.href='newurl.html', but not working.

can anyone tell me what should i add on the js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So add an event listener

```
s.cover.addEventListener("click", function () {
   window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
});
```

Comment: Worth pointing out if the url location can differ, it can be set in a data-* attribute and retrieved on click, however if url doesn't change, this answer will do the job.